# Could you possibly have a script in an HTML textarea/textfield and have it executed?

Tags: javascript, html, scripting, textarea, textfield

Someone brought up an argument that having a textarea that accepts too many characters may be risky because people may put script in there.

In my entire existence, I've never heard of that possibility.
Could anyone shed some light as whether or not it is possible to have a script in a text form field and somehow have it executed?

Comment: You're vulnerable to XSS if you accept text input, but setting a limit on how long the text can be doesn't fix the vulnerability at all.

Comment: Well, if you allow user to input HTML for, let say a CMS, then yes, it could be dangerous.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon can you elaborate on how dangerous it could be?
Let's say I have a form field, and the 'Description' text field happens to be very loooong! How could the "script" user put in the form field be dangerous to my system in any way?

Comment: I'll throw together some examples for you in an answer, hold on

Comment: @abcXYZ - that all depends on how much an attacker can make use of the ability to exploit your site. In some cases - it could be very dangerous. In others, not so much.

Answer (score 3):

Yes - this is how XSS works. Very simply- you can add script stuff to the dom and execute it that way. For instance, this would fire an alert:

```
$('#myDiv').html('<script type="text/javascript">alert("hello world");</script>');
```

## [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JWells/yNUQT/)

Answer (score 1):

Any time you deal with use input, you're at risk of XSS vulnerabilities.

Let's say you have a simple HTML form like this:

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post">
<textarea name="insecuretext"></textarea>
</form>
```

And then on your server you have something like this:

```
<div class="usercontent">
<?php echo $_POST["insecuretext"]; ?>
</div>
```

For 99% of your users, this will work perfectly, but what if someone submitted this?

```
<script>somethingEvil();</script>
```

Your HTML would look like this:

```
<div class="usercontent">
<script>somethingEvil();</script>
</div>
```

And then anyone who looks at that page will be affected by the JavaScript.

A really easy solution is to sanitize your input by calling `strip_tags()`

```
<div class="usercontent">
<?php echo strip_tags($_POST["insecuretext"]); ?>
</div>
```

Now, unless your attacker is really clever, you're not vulnerable to XSS in this situation.

Another common situation is if you put insecure content as an attribute of an element. I saw an example of this on a forum a while back where the developers put the contents of the post in a `data-content` attribute for some reason.

```
<div class="forum_post" data-content="<?php echo $_POST["insecuretext"]; ?>"></div>
```

I was able to break this by submitting something like:

```
foo" onload="somethingEvil();"> <!--
```

Which printed out as `<div class="forum_post" data-content="foo" onload="somethingEvil();"> <!-- ></div>`

In this case, all that needed to be done was to convert my special characters to entities:

```
<div class="forum_post" data-content="<?php echo htmlentities($_POST["insecuretext"]); ?>"></div>
```

Which would look like this:

```
<div class="forum_post" data-content="foo&quot; onload=&quot;somethingEvil();&quot;&gt; &lt;!-- "></div>
```

So here's what you should take from this:

- Don't trust your users under any circumstances
- Never print unsanitized or unvalidated user input
- Understand XSS techniques and how to stop them
- Know when you could potentially be vulnerable and what you'll do if an attacker gets through your defenses
- Understand that length isn't related to security at all. Unless you limit your input to like 3 characters, it could potentially be dangerous.

Comment: well then this isn't a big problem as I'd expected. :D
We always properly escape html content from form POST.
Thanks for the example, btw!